# Android build package size is too large

Tags: android, react-native, build, sdk

we use android SDK to use react-native project. I added but when i try to publish my app package-size is too large. I use jitpack for android sdk.

I tried some changing for build.gradle but i could not fix.

```
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable true
            universalApk false
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

I expected nearly 20mb for npm publish package size , but it is showing 440mb.

Comment: please analyse apk from `build -> Analyse Apk` from there you can understand why apk 440mb

Comment: @Basi, this is a bridge project , i want to npm publish this project to send expo project. This is why i can not get download and analyse apk. When i clear build cache and rebuild react-native download too much dependecies,  builder, fastUtil, kotlin, intellij file e.t.c.